# How can I append an id to href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter-3

I don't know what is the correct term for my question, but I want to put the customer id to the href, like **href='index.php/site/get_all_services_ajax/{obj.customer[i].customer_id}**.

See line 5 in my code. How can I do that?

```
<div id='mycoord'></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/site/get_all_customer_ajax', function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data)
            for (var i=0; i < obj.customer.length; i++)
            {
                $('#mycoord').append("<a href='<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/site/get_customer_info/{obj.customer[i].customer_id}' <h2>" + obj.customer[i].first_name + "</href></h2><br>");
            }
        })
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't build JS with PHP, and definitely don't build JS to build HTML with PHP. The amount of escaping needed to make stuff work becomes significantly more complex.

Comment: why? i am just making a simple viewing..

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick -

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $.get('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/site/get_all_customer_ajax', function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data)
            for (var i=0;i <obj.customer.length;i++)
            {
            $('#mycoord').append("<a href='<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/site/get_customer_info/{"+obj.customer[i].customer_id+"}' <h2>" + obj.customer[i].first_name + "</href></h2><br>");
            }

        })
     });
```

Comment: Thank you it works. 10000000000000000000 pts for you.